# Sitecore 9.3 Change Select Rendering Dialog size

Tags: experience-editor

I am trying to change the default size of the "Select a Rendering" Dialog.

[image]

it would be ok if I change the size of every dialog box, not just this one.

I've tried to override the css, but I was not able to change the dialog size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to override it for all dialogs, you can change it in file:

```
sitecore\shell\Controls\JqueryModalDialogs.html
```

Find

```
`function showModalDialog`
```

and when `dialogOptions` variable is initialized, use any value you want for `width` property:

```
var dialogOptions = {
    closeText: top.scForm.translate("Close"),
    modal: true,
    draggable: !isMobileBrowser(),
    height: dialogHeight,
    width: YOUR_VALUE_HERE, // HERE <------
    resizable: isResizable,
    dialogClass: isClosable ? '' : 'no-close',
    title: '',
    open: function () {
      contentIframe.dialog('widget').css('opacity', 0.001);
    },
    close: function () {
      window.top.dialogClose();
    },
    beforeClose: modifiedHandling
  };
```

You can check `url` parameter first and change width of the dialog only when it's `Select Rendering` dialog.

Remember that Sitecore caches scripts heavily, so best open new private tab after or start developer tools and check "Disable Cache" option.